# A property of quadratic complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=az^2+bz+c \qquad a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$$

> If $f$ is non-zero everywhere in the unit disc $|z|\leq1$, then $|c|>|a|$

The non zero part hinted at the minimum modulus principle. As it takes the value $c$ on the boundary as well as at the origin. However I could really get anywhere. Any hints/solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:  the two complex roots $z_1, z_2$  of the quadratic equation $f(z)=0$ must therefore lie outside the unit circle, meaning $|z_1|, |z_2| \gt 1$. By Vieta's relations, their product is $z_1 z_2 = c/a\,$.

Comment: Ow, that was so simple :/. Thanks